# Heroku Spring Boot Aplication error code=H14 status=503

Tags: java, spring, heroku, deployment

I deploy spring boot application on heroku server. Unfortunately I have problem to connect with application.

Heroku logs:

```
2022-07-10T12:34:14.901062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/test" host=hquiz123.herokuapp.com request_id=edf9a13d-cac7-456c-9926-ebbbc612a336 fwd="194.150.250.3" dyno= connect
= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Application controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test" )
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestController {


    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Procfile with this command:

```
     web: java -Dspring.profiles.active=default -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar
```

Then on the heroku CLI, enter the following:

```
     heroku ps:scale web=1
```

For more details, please check here : https://www.autoscripts.net/heroku-no-web-processes-running-spring-boot/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).